# AWS ECS Service Discovery for multiple tasks

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-route53, service-discovery

If I have an ECS service, which can scale out, or always runs more than one task, is load balancing handled by the built-in service discovery?

I mean, if my service A is running 3 tasks, and another service B is making requests using the domain name, generated for A by service discovery, how will it decide where a request goes?

Answer (score 0):

[From this Medium article](https://medium.com/containers-on-aws/how-to-setup-service-discovery-in-elastic-container-service-3d18479959e6), it appears that route 53 is going to use its own catalog of healthy instances to determine which service to route to. So yes, load balancing will occur in that way.